# ClickOnce - URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697191'

Tags: .net, iis, clickonce

I'm getting this wired error message while trying to install the application from clickonce.

> URLDownloadToCacheFile failed with HRESULT '-2146697191' Error: An error occurred trying to download 'https://SomeWebSite.com/SomeApplication.application'

The certificate we are using is configured properly.
I googled this problem and tried every suggested solution but nothing is changed.
If we put the address in the url, it works just fine and install the app, but when clicking on 'Install' on the clickonce, it doesnt work.